# How can I get Credit info Correctly without Integration of any payment method in WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, integration, payment-gateway

How are you? I hope that you all are fine. Basically I have WooCommerce site. I want to accept credit card payment correctly without using PayPal and stripe or any other gateway. So my question is how can I accept card payments manually in WordPress. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When WooCommerce is installed and activated, it has 3 payment methods. Direct bank transfer, Check payments, and Cash on delivery. You can't take credit card payment without any additional payment methods like paypal or stripe.

Also, WooCommerce have an extension named WooCommerce Payments which can help you. But it has country restrictions.

Check this extension : https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-payments/?quid=c5d1d45a9bf2f539fea9a745ae8287a9

Hope it will help you.